# Low bound for Serre's vanishing of $\mathcal{O}_X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a projective variety over a noetherian ring and let $L=\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ be a very ample line bundle. If $F$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$ Serre's vanishing theorem tells us that there is $n_0$ depending on $F$ s.t. for $i>0$ and $n \geq n_0$, $H^i(X,F(n))=0$.

Let $F=\mathcal{O}_X$, how to find $n_0$ that works in this case? Is it true that $n_0=1$? In other words a very ample line bundle does not have any higher cohomology.

Comment: I know it is true for $X$ being an abelian variety. Perhaps [this paper](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~totaro/papers/public_html/ample.pdf) is helpful.

Comment: You can use Kodaira vanishing (in cahracteristic zero).